# Rails params for email thread...struggling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to build an internal app. I have a model with emails. Each email has an id. However, I have a view that displays the distinct email threads with this query:

```
@subjects = Email.all(:group => "title")
```

I am displaying results with the following code.

```
<% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= subject.title %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I want the user to be able to click on one of those distinct titles and go to a page that displays all the emails that match that title.

I've researched passing parameters and I'm just not quite sure what to do. As it stands, I was trying something like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Show thread', :action => :thread, :title => subject.title %>
```

Which generates a nice, handy URL. But this doesn't seem to work:

```
@emails = Email.find(params[:title])
```

Helps, hints or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're searching for a record that has its id equal to the value of the title. You should do the match against the title field instead.

If you want to retrieve a single record

```
@emails = Email.where(title: params[:title]).first
```

or

```
@emails = Email.find_by_title(params[:title])
```

If you want to retrieve multiple records

```
@emails = Email.where(title: params[:title])
```

Comment: That worked great until I tried to pull them out in the view. I am using @emails = Email.find_by_title(params[:title]) ... and in the view, I have @emails.each do |s| and I'm getting the error "undefined method `each' for #<Email:0x23e2648>"

Comment: Nevermind. I'm an idiot. I changed it to @emails = Email.find_all_by_title(params[:title]) and it worked.